# How to float a word next to animated text

Tags: css, animation, css-float, css-transitions, css-animations

**I'm a completely new to animating text in CSS3, and I have two problems I can't quite figure out.**

**Problem 1:**
I've been trying to float a regular word next to my animated text so it's all in one sentence. The animated word will be close to the end of the sentence and would take up the require space depending on the length of the word.

> **Janie is a lovely girl because she is (animated text) and cool.**

**Problem 2:**
My second issue started when I added extra words for a total of 12 animated words. This caused a looping issue with words appearing on top of each other I'm not sure what to change in terms of the keyframes to make the words all loop how they're supposed to.

Any help or push in the right direction will be extremely helpful at this point. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgrvaqfg/)

Thanks in advanced!

**HTML:**

```
<section class="wrapper">

  <h2 class="sentence">Janie is a lovely girl because she is
    <div class="slidingVertical">
    <span>amazing</span>
    <span>beautiful</span>
    <span>cute</span>
    <span>honest</span>
    <span>cool</span>
    <span>brave</span>
    <span>wild</span>
    <span>interesting</span>
    <span>local</span>
    <span>sexy</span>
    <span>intelligent</span>
    <span>exotic</span>
    </div>

 <p>
  and cool. 
 </p>
  </h2>


</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*Heading1*/
h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
     color: #222;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: left;
}
/*Wrapper*/
.wrapper{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 40px 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
}

/*Vertical Sliding*/
.slidingVertical{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.slidingVertical span{
    animation: topToBottom 10.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: topToBottom 10.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: topToBottom 10.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
}

/*topToBottom Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*Horizontal Sliding*/
.slidingHorizontal{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.slidingHorizontal span{
    animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*leftToRight Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes leftToRight{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes leftToRight{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes leftToRight{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateX(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateX(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*FadeIn*/
.fadeIn{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.fadeIn span{
    animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*FadeIn Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes fadeEffect{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadeEffect{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*Vertical Flip*/
.verticalFlip{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.verticalFlip span{
    animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*Vertical Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*Horizontal Flip*/
.horizontalFlip{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.horizontalFlip span{
    animation: horizontal 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: horizontal 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: horizontal 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.horizontalFlip span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.horizontalFlip span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.horizontalFlip span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.horizontalFlip span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*Horizontal Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes horizontal{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes horizontal{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes horizontal{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*AntiClockWise Effect*/
.antiClock{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.antiClock span{
    animation: anti 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: anti 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: anti 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.antiClock span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.antiClock span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.antiClock span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.antiClock span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*AntiClockWise Effect Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes anti{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes anti{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes anti{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*ClockWise Effect*/
.clockWise{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.clockWise span{
    animation: clock 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: clock 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: clock 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.clockWise span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.clockWise span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.clockWise span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.clockWise span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

.clockWise span:nth-child(6){
    animation-delay: 11s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 11s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 11s;
}

/*ClockWise Effect Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes clock{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes clock{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes clock{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*Pop Effect*/
.popEffect{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.popEffect span{
    animation: pop 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: pop 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: pop 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.popEffect span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.popEffect span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.popEffect span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.popEffect span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*Pop Effect Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes pop{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.10) skew(0deg) translate(0px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes pop{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.10) skew(0deg) translate(0px);}
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes pop{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.10) skew(0deg) translate(0px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*Push Effect*/
.pushEffect{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.pushEffect span{
    animation: push 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: push 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: push 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.pushEffect span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.pushEffect span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.pushEffect span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.pushEffect span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*Push Effect Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes push{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(0px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes push{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(0px);}
        10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes push{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(0px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
/*Footer*/
h3{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Fixing the overlapping of the words would be simple enough but getting the word to line-up properly would be tough because you have sentence before & after the animated text and the animated text has words of different width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set all the main elements to be inline.

The exception would be the span,that needs to be block, to be able to make the container autoadjust.

And the animations need to be overlapping in time.

```css
.sentence {
  display: inline-block;
  verflow: hidden;
  height: 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sentence p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.slidingVertical {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.slidingVertical span {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.slidingVertical span {
  animation: elements 10s infinite linear;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -6s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -7s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -8s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: -9s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: -10s;
}

@keyframes elements {
   0% {
     opacity: 0;
     max-width: 10px;
   }
   5%, 10% {
     opacity: 1;
     max-width: 400px;
   }
   15%, 100% {
     opacity: 0;
     max-width: 10px;
   }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="sentence">Janie is a 
    <div class="slidingVertical">
    <span>cute</span>
    <span>wild</span>
    <span>amazingly cute</span>
    <span>very beatiful and amazingly cute</span>
    <span>beautiful</span>
    <span>honest</span>
    <span>cool</span>
    <span>brave</span>
    <span>interesting</span>
    <span>local</span>
    </div>
    <p>girl</p>
  </h2>
</section>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you @vals for all the help.

Comment: Happy that it helped !